# Ajax POST form to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, html

Trying to post my form using Ajax. Using Apache Cordova but can't seem to send it to my php form. Any ideas of how to get my form to work would be appreciated.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">    
$('#userform').submit(function(){
    var postData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData,
        url: 'http://myurl/dbInsertUserslocal.php',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert('User successfully added');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(data);
            alert('There was an error adding New User');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

and my form looks like:

```
      <form id="userform" method="Post">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <label>First/Last Name
        <input type="text" name="firstlast" />
      </label>
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
      <label>Title
        <select name="title" >
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Inspector">Inspector</option>
          <option value="Tech">Technician</option>
          <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
        </select>
      </label>
  </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row" >
        <div class="large-12 columns">  
           <hr class="intro-divider">
                <input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" 
                     id="snap" name="photo">
                      </div>
                           </div>
               <hr class="intro-divider">   
           </div>
         </div>
       <div class="row">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <button class="tiny" type="submit" value="Submit" 
             id="submit" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Add User</button>
    </div>
     </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? Can you paste some errors from browser console? It should be in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: So you didn't mention what the actual problem is.  Does you ajax call not get triggered? Does the data not post correctly to your server-side script?  Does you server-side script not work properly? What is the actual problem?

Comment: What are you doing on php-side? Did you try a simple `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: That's the thing. in console, im not even getting any errors. The form clears and shows nothing. no errors or anything.

Comment: if I send my form without ajax it posts without issue to the php page. I need to use ajax as I am converting this into a mobile application using Cordova Phonegap.

Comment: @MizAkita OK you definitely should update this question to include your on-device use case.  You have now ventured into the realm of cross-origin resource sharing (CORS), which means you need to either modify your ajax and server-sdie script to utilize jsonp and/or properly configure CORS policies on the server that serves as AJAX endpoint.

Comment: Well, as of right now i dont have my ondeviceload settings in there. I am just trying to get ajax to work. What i posted is how my form looks.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the file in form, you must use `multipart/form-data`.

```
<form id="userform" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

`serialize` method can't see the file data.
By using the `FormData` object instead of `serialize` method, the javascripts code becomes

```
$(function(){
$('#userform').submit(function(){
    var fd = new FormData( $(this)[0] );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: fd,
        dataType: "text",
        url: 'http://myurl/dbInsertUserslocal.php',
        success: function(data){
            alert( data );
            alert('User successfully added');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('There was an error adding New User');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

However, some devices does not equip the FormData object.
Check
http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData

Comment: ill give it a try now.